# importing excel onto sharepoint and use the data to build reports?

Tags: excel

Is it possible to do this with sharepoint? I have read quite a few introductory articles that seems to hint on the possibly of acheiving this, but I couldn't find any tutorials on it. Can someone point me at the right directions please?
What I am looking for is something like read csv from a list of files, then use the data to populate views, creating dashboard and all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "Custom List in Datasheet View" and customize it so that it has the same columns/fields as an excelfile and then copy/paste the content from Excel to the SharePoint list. After that You can create reports via Excel Services etc.
[image: Custom list in Datasheet view]